# Switching background images with javascript forces absolute path

Tags: javascript, background-image

I have a div that begins as follows:

```
<div id="info_picture" style="background-image: url('assets/img/channels/banners/3')"></div>
```

The reason there's no file extension for the image is that it can be uploaded by the user, and I don't want to store the extension in the database (or force them to only use one image format). I have a line of javascript that changes this background image:

```
info_picture.style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/img/channels/banners/"+channel+"')";
```

However, on inspecting the element, the background image style appears as the absolute path, rather than the relative path I specified in the script. That's a problem, because without the extension, that causes it to be transferred with application/octet-stream. Then chrome chucks a warning, and the image doesn't display. How can I force it to load the relative path instead of the absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut says it's not a javascript problem or browser issue.

The problem may be in the actual file, and the file actually has application/octet-stream as mime type.

If I were you,

1. I wouldn't use assets directory to serve image. My choice would be public/images directory at least. assets are not for dynamic files, but for static files.
2. If the image are served from server without extension name, I would serve images from 
   application by setting mime types properly through your controller, guessing you use rails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your folder structure, but you can use "../" for every folder you want relatively to go up from the place you execute code in.

Try:

```
info_picture.style.backgroundImage = "url('../assets/img/channels/banners/"+channel+"')";
```

And see how path will change.